# Select the record with highest date and INCLUDE relevant tables with it - LINQ

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-sql

I have a table called `EmployementContracts`, I want to retrieve each contract with highest `StartDate` for every employee, included some other properties from linked/relevant tables. I tried as bellow:

```
_dbContext.EmployementContracts
                .Include(x => x.Employee)
                .Include(x => x.Department)
                .Where(x => x.SupervisorId == 1)
                .GroupBy(c => c.EmployeeId)
                .Select(g => new
                {
                    StartDate = g.Max(x => x.StartDate)
                }).ToList();
```

I am able to get only the `StartDate` column from this (the highest dates for every record), but how to get some other properties from included tables?

for example I need:
`EmployeeName` from `Employee` and `DepartmentName` from `Department` tables as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you use the following code:

```
_dbContext.EmployeeContracts
   .Where(x => x.SuperVisorId == 1)
   .GroupBy(x => x.EmployeeId)
   .Select(x=>x.OrderByDescending(y=>y.StartDate).FirstOrDefault())
   .Include(x => x.Employee)
   .Include(x => x.Department)
   .ToList();
```

The trick is the only retrieve the relevant record from the grouping. Then each record from each group is exactly the employeeContract you want to look at. Notice also that the .Include() statements are moved to the back. This is because the grouping changes the Queryable structure and removes the included navigation properties, so you'll have to Include once you have the structure you desire.

Answer (score 0):

Your select statement is the result you're going to get.  Your result is just an anonymous object with one field, `StartDate`.  You can just call `.Select()` there to return your entire search and the tables and data to the anonymous object.

Comment: Could you please let me know where to add the `.Select()` for returning entire result set? If you can decorate my select statement with it.

Comment: @wkhaksar You already have the Select() method but you're adding code to Select a specific component.  Just call Select() without all the g => new ...  Code inside of it.